# Add a user to a SharePoint site collection using Office 365 Graph API

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I need to add a new user to a site collection via the Office 365 Graph API. Is it possible? If so, what would the REST call look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a user via the Office Graph Api.
Instead, you can add you user with the Azure Api in the Azure Directory linked to you Office 365 tenant with this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn776330.aspx#CreateUser

Then your user will be accessible in your site collection.